# Merge related activities and related groups options not available in merge contacts

Tags: activities, duplicate-contacts

We've recently upgraded a site to 4.6.10

When merging duplicate contacts the options to merge activities and groups (and tags and events etc) are missing.

I've tried merging a couple of dummy contacts. Contact data merges as expected, but associated group and activity data is deleted along with the duplicate contact not transferred to the remaining contact.

The demo work displays as expected. Are there any settings that control this activity that I've overlooked?

Has anybody experienced this issue before?

Any hints/tips/pointers as to where I can look?

Thanks

Craig

Comment: Is this behavior something you can replicate on the demo server at demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: Hi Jon,

Yes I have, but as I typed in a rush I realised I'd garbled that part of my post.

The demo site works,as I'd expect it to work. All related activities and relationships are listed and merge without problem :)

Comment: The demo site will be using 4.6.11 now, you could try upgrading to see if that fixes the issue. A number of other issues to do with merging were fixed as part of that release too: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20%22Fixed%2FCompleted%22%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%204.6.11%20AND%20text%20~%20%22merg%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found that there have been a few database schema issues. By rebuilding the schema and checking foreign keys, this issue has been resolved! Phew.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to the latest release.

(NB I realise I may not be adding much to above comments but am trying to get some unanswered questions answered as that is currently the 'weakest' aspect of our Beta civicrm stackexchange according to these [stats][1])

Comment: Thanks Pete,

We had two unrelated sites with this issue. Upgrading Civi versions didn't fix the problem.

On one site we fixed the problem by updating the database schema (and we're waiting for time to try that approach on the second site).

I'm not sure of the full steps in this process so I'm going to ask a colleague to add a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thx Craig - an answer will help the community